# InnoDB deadlock with lock modes S and X

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb, deadlock

In my application, I have two queries that occur from time to time (from different processes), that cause a deadlock.

**Query #1**

```
UPDATE tblA, tblB SET tblA.varcharfield=tblB.varcharfield WHERE tblA.varcharfield IS NULL AND [a few other conditions];
```

**Query #2**

```
INSERT INTO tmp_tbl SELECT * FROM tblA WHERE [various conditions];
```

Both of these queries take a significant time, as these tables have millions of rows.  When query #2 is running, it seems that `tblA` is locked in mode `S`.  It seems that query #1 requires an `X` lock.  Since this is incompatible with an `S` lock, query #1 waits for up to 30 seconds, at which point I get a deadlock:

> Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

Based on what I've read [in the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-lock-modes.html), I think I have a couple options:

1. Set an index on tblA.varcharfield.  Unfortunately, I think that this would require a very large index to store the field of varchar(512).  *(See edit below... this didn't work.)*
2. Disable locking with `SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;`
   .  I don't understand the implications of this, and am worried about corrupt data.  I don't use explicit transactions in my application currently, but I might at some point in the future.
3. Split my time-consuming queries into small pieces so that they can queue and run in MySQL without reaching the 30-second timeout.  This wouldn't really fix the heart of the issue, and I am concerned that when my database servers get busy that the problem will occur again.
4. Simply retrying queries over and over again... not an option I am hoping for.

**How should I proceed?  Are there alternate methods I should consider?**

---

**EDIT:**  I have tried setting an index on varcharfield, but the table is still locking.  I suspect that the locking happens when the `UPDATE` portion is actually executing.  Are there other suggestions to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by adding explicit `LOCK TABLE` statements around both queries.  This turned out to be a better solution, since each query affects so many records, and that both of these are background processes.  They now wait on each other.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

While this is an okay solution for me, it obviously isn't the answer for everyone.  Locking with `WRITE` means that you cannot `READ`.  Only a `READ` lock will allow others to `READ`.

Answer (score 1):

A. If we assume that indexing `varcharField` takes a lot of disk space and adding new column will not hit you hard I can suggest the following approach:

1. create new field with datatype "tinyint"
2. index it.
3. this field will store 0 if `varcharField` is null and 1 - otherwise.
4. rewrite the first query to do update relying on new field. In this case it will not cause entire table locking.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I have tried using an index, as suggested by Darhazer, but to no avail.  I suspect that the `UPDATE` has to run before my `SELECT` will be allowed to run.  Do you have any other advice?

Comment: If it's still a problem could you please put the result of `show innodb status`, section "deadlocks"

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I solved the problem by explicitly locking the tables.  Unfortunately, I think the deadlock must have been caused by other parts of the query that I can't divulge due to NDA.  My simplification of the query in question was not adequate.  I do thank you for your help though, in solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can index only part of the varchar column, it will still work, and will require less space. Just specify index size:

```
CREATE INDEX someindex ON sometable (varcharcolumn(32))
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I tried this last night, but am still getting the deadlock.  I've ran `EXPLAIN` on the `SELECT` queries, and they are all using indices as expected.  I suspect that the `UPDATE` has to run before my `SELECT` will work at all.

Comment: @Brad can you add the explains to the question? I would like to take a look at them

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help.  I was able to get around this problem by locking the tables explicitly.  I think the problem was part of the query that I can't divulge due to NDA, and my simplification in my question didn't not adequately show the issue.  Thanks again for your assistance though!